# What is magnifying power of a convex lens of focal length $5\,\mathrm{cm}$ when image is formed at infinity?

Tags: optics, lenses

Magnifying power of convex lens is usually $1+ d/f$ so if $d$ is infinity then what would be the answer I thought of 1 but my book says its 5, also I know that if image is at infinity then object must be placed at $f$ but I can't figure out how to solve this.